# Cannot login into gitolite server to clone, but can connect via ssh

Tags: git, ssh, gitolite

While there are [several](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9339272/gitolite-can-connect-via-ssh-cant-clone) [questions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6366363/gitolite-installation-i-cannot-clone-gitolite-admin-repo) with [similar](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4976397/gitosis-gitolite-setup) symptoms, none are exactly the same, nor do the solutions presented there solve my issue.

I have set up gitolite successfully, as far as I am aware, using [these instructions](http://gitolite.com/gitolite/progit.html), and after overcoming [this issue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16151528/gitolite-setup-getting-fatal-fingerprinting-failed-for-tmp-q3pne4wvbu/). The host user is `git`, and I have set up the following .ssh/config file on my workstation:

```
Host admin
    Hostname server.com
    User git
    IdentityFile ~/.ssh/admin


Host dev
    Hostname server.com
    User git
    IdentityFile ~/.ssh/micha
```

I can ssh using the admin config with `ssh admin` and get the following response:

```
stdin: is not a tty
hello admin, this is git@hostname running gitolite3 v3.5.1-2-g962e465 on git 1.7.10.2

 R W    gitolite-admin
 R W    testing
Connection to xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx closed.
```

Whenever I try to clone the gitolite-admin repo, however I get the following response:

```
Cloning into 'gitolite-admin'...
fatal: Could not read from remote repository.

Please make sure you have the correct access rights
and the repository exists.
```

According to the previous ssh response, I do have access rights. I have also verified that the git user is owner of the repository files on the server. After researching this, I have changed local GIT_SSH from TortoisePlink.exe to C:\Program Files (x86)\Git\bin\ssh.exe and still get the same response. All the following variations of the clone command elicit the same response:

- 'git clone admin:gitolite-admin'
- 'git clone admin:gitolite-admin.git'
- 'git clone admin:repositories/gitolite-admin'
- 'git clone admin:~/repositories/gitolite-admin'
- 'git clone ssh://admin:gitolite-admin'
- 'git clone git@admin:gitolite-admin'
- all sorts of permutations of the above variations.

I am now at a loss as to how to overcome this problem.

Answer (score 1):

It turns out I HAD fixed the problem, I just needed to close the git-bash and restart it. Changing the GIT_SSH variable from TortoisePlink to C:\Program Files (x86)\Git\bin\ssh.exe as shown in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8713121/283991) was what was needed.

Naively perhaps, I thought the variable would be parsed each time the git clone command was used, but once I restarted the git-bash, the git clone command worked!